# UIBarButtonSystemItem PageCurl does not change color with the toolbar

Tags: iphone, colors, toolbar, page-curl, tint

I wanted to change the color of the navigation bar and tool bar, but the color of the page curl system icon `UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl` does not change with the tool bar tint color. If I use other system icons like bookmark, they will change. Does anyone have a solution for this sort of problem?

I used the following lines to change the color of the navigation bar and the tool bar.

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.navigationController.toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Here is a screenshot showing that the Page Curl color does not change:

[image: Page Curl]

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `tintColor` for `UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl` before adding it to the toolbar? This was certainly an issue when I last looked in iOS 4.3.

Comment: UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl was added to the tool bar by UI Builder.

Comment: OK. I removed UIBarButtonItem for the page curl icon, and added a new one programatically. The problem was solved!

Comment: i tried this same solution out, and i don't get a redColor curlButton.  Chris, do you have a code-snippet showing how this worked for you?

Comment: It only works for the standard color and black color. It seems it changes with color of the toolbar style.          self.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;