# Why can't I change UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl item tint?

Tags: iphone, uitoolbar, page-curl, tint, uitoolbaritem

I am using iOS 5.1 with StoryBoards. I want to change the tint of the standard page curl button, but I don't seem to be able too.

The button is on a View Controller and is a pushed View Controller of a Navigation Controller. The toolbar is inferred, as I changed the tint on the Navigation Controller. The toolbar appears in the desired color.

My viewDidLoad method is as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // adjust the color of the curl button
    if (self.curlButton) {
        NSMutableArray * toolbarItems = [self.toolbarItems mutableCopy];
        [toolbarItems removeObject:self.curlButton];
        UIColor *barColor = self.navigationController.toolbar.tintColor;
        UIBarButtonItem *newPageCurl = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl target:self.curlButton.target action:self.curlButton.action];
        newPageCurl.tintColor = barColor;
        NSLog(@"%@", newPageCurl.tintColor);
        [toolbarItems addObject:newPageCurl];
        self.toolbarItems = toolbarItems;
    }
}
```

`self.curlButton` is an outlet for the page curl button that is configured in Interface Builder.

I already tried just setting the tint in `self.curlButton`, which is initially nil, but that didn't work, the button was the same blue tint.

Some of the answers on SO say you have to create a new button programmatically, which is what I am trying here.

I have verified that the `barColor` contains the correct color.  I commented out the `removeObject` line and that correctly produced two curl buttons, but both were blue.

The NSLog verifies that the `newPageCurl` button has the correct tint set.

I tried doing all this in `viewDidAppear` instead, in case the toolbar needed to be displayed first, but the button was still blue and didn't use the new tint.

Answer (score 0):

starting in iOS 5, you should be able to use appearance selector to do this.

(edit, sorry to have led astray w.r.t. the curl button.  the appearance or appearanceWhenContainedIn: appear to work for everything except the curl button … even other system bar button items.  for curl, one user said that the solution at [UIBarButtonSystemItem PageCurl does not change color with the toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11123883/774691) worked, but when i tested it out, it didn't work for me.)

```
    if ([[UIBarButtonItem class] respondsToSelector:@selector(appearanceWhenContainedIn:)])
    {
        id barButtonAppearance
          = [UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil];
        [barButtonAppearance setTintColor:self.navigationController.toolbar.tintColor];
        barButtonAppearance
          = [UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIToolBar class], nil];
        // you'll have to have toolbar already, or pick something like [UIColor chartreuseColor] or whatever
        [barButtonAppearance setTintColor:toolbar.tintColor];
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't change the color of the page curl button.  It also has the unwanted side effect of changing the standard button icons from white to the tint color of the tool bar.

Comment: updated, with link for a real solution to you, and a better solution w.r.t. making sure the buttons only change in the appropriate bars.

Comment: hmmm ... perhaps i should give up on this question.  i just tried the suggestion at the linked answer myself, and while the user of the linked answer said it worked for him, it did not work for me.

Comment: I'm ready to give up and create custom graphics for my own curl button.